# Char shifting for given string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Suppose we have a varchar value like 'Durgesh' and I want to increase (Char +2) of every characters which are given in 'Durgesh'. Example:

- D --> F
- U --> W
- R --> T
- G --> I
- E --> G
- S --> U
- H --> J
- So if we put the parameter 'Durgesh', then we need the output 'Fwtiguj'.

How can I implement this with a SQL query?

Comment: Write a stored procedure and loop through the characters.  Also, explain what happens with Y and Z.  And what about non-alphabetic characters?

Comment: Hey @GordonLinoff, we will get the output according to Ascii values of every characters.

Comment: Give this a shot. Might be close to what you want. `CHAR(ASCII(@var)+2)`

Comment: Hi @DurgeshVerma I see you are, lets say, new on this forum so please note: When someone answer the question you asked(and you did asked for help) then it is a good thing to get a feedback from you. You can comment the answer to say what is wrong with it and if it is correct you can accept it as correct. This is a good way because of more than just one reason. P.S. Soon you will be able to also up vote an answer.

Comment: Hi @VBoka, Thank you for your feed back. Actually I am new user of stack overflow and unable to vote due to some criteria matching policy on website, but i will take care of these things in future.

Comment: Hi @DurgeshVerma, yes, as I have wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be your function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[shifting](@Input varchar(100))  
RETURNS varchar(100)   
AS   
BEGIN  
   declare

    @i INT=0,
    @a varchar(100) =''

    while @i<LEN(@Input)
    BEGIN 

       SET @i = @i +1
       set @a = @a + char(ascii(substring(@Input,@i,1))+2)

   end
       RETURN @a
END
```

You call it as:

```
select [dbo].[shifting]('Durgesh') as [a]
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8d682985f7cb61777c38bda041f0b8b5)

Here is a new function that will resolve the YZ and yz problem:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[shifting](@Input varchar(100))  
RETURNS varchar(100)   
AS   
BEGIN  
   declare

    @i INT=0,
    @a varchar(100) =''

    while @i<LEN(@Input)
    BEGIN 

       SET @i = @i +1
    if substring(@Input,@i,1) in ('y','Y') 
       if ascii(substring(@Input,@i,1)) = ascii('y') 
          set @a = @a + 'a'
       else
          set @a = @a + 'A'
    else
    if substring(@Input,@i,1) in ('z','Z') 
       if ascii(substring(@Input,@i,1)) = ascii('z') 
          set @a = @a + 'b'
       else
          set @a = @a + 'B'
    else
       set @a = @a + char(ascii(substring(@Input,@i,1))+2)
   end
       RETURN @a
END
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e3b017a41b74e27430f725effc9316b8)

Comment: Thank you @VBoka. This query is much familiar but its not working on last characters like (Y,Z) and result should be (A,B).

Comment: Hi @DurgeshVerma I have updated my answer with another function. Please check.

Comment: HI @VBoka, Yes this code is fulfilling all the criteria which required. Thank alot.. !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily with a tally table. I keep one on my database a view. Here is the code for my tally table. The biggest advantage a tally table has here is we don't have to do any looping!!!

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
```

Now that we have a tally table we can use it to make your character shift. This will work on nearly any string (until you hit the top end of the ASCII values).

```
declare @Val varchar(10) = 'Durgesh'

select stuff((
    select char(ASCII(substring(@Val, t.N, 1)) + 2)
    from cteTally t
    where t.N <= len(@Val)
    order by t.N
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 0, '')
```

--EDIT--

Here is a new version that will "wrap" the characters back to the beginning.

```
declare @Val varchar(100) = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

select stuff((
    select case when (ASCII(substring(@Val, t.N, 1)) > 88 AND ASCII(substring(@Val, t.N, 1)) < 91) --Upper case
                    OR ASCII(substring(@Val, t.N, 1)) > 120 --lower case
                then char(ASCII(substring(@Val, t.N, 1)) - 24) else char(ASCII(substring(@Val, t.N, 1)) + 2) end
    from cteTally t
    where t.N <= len(@Val)
    order by t.N
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 0, '')
```

Comment: Thank you @Sean. This query is much familiar but its not working on last characters like (Y,Z) and result should be (A,B).

Comment: @DurgeshVerma just needed a slight adjustment to accommodate this. I know you have already checked one solution as the answer but looping will kill your performance for large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code :-

```
declare @val varchar(10) = 'Durgesh'
DECLARE @i INT = 0
WHILE @i < LEN(@val)
BEGIN 
    PRINT( CHAR( ASCII(SUBSTRING(@val,@i,1)) +2  ) ) 
    SET @i =  @i + 1
End
```

Comment: Thank you @Adnan Sir for help.